# MongoDB count without duplicate by given id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm the begginner in Mongodb and given my data below

```
{ "client_id" : 1, "invoice":[{"invoice_date" : "20-07-2020", "invoice_month" : "July 2020","account_status" : "Active"}]}
{ "client_id" : 1, "invoice":[{"invoice_date" : "20-07-2020", "invoice_month" : "July 2020","account_status" : "Active"}]}
{ "client_id" : 1, "invoice":[{"invoice_date" : "30-07-2020", "invoice_month" : "July 2020","account_status" : "Active"}]}
{ "client_id" : 2, "invoice":[{"invoice_date" : "03-08-2020", "invoice_month" : "August 2020","account_status" : "Active"}]}
{ "client_id" : 2, "invoice":[{"invoice_date" : "05-05-2020", "invoice_month" : "August 2020","account_status" : "Active"}]}
{ "client_id" : 3, "invoice":[{"invoice_date" : "10-06-2020", "invoice_month" : "June 2020","account_status" : "Active"}]}
```

I want count without all duplicate values and mentioned below **expected result**

```
{"client_id": 2 , "invoice_month" : "August 2020", "count": 1}
{"client_id": 1 , "invoice_month" : "July 2020", "count": 1}
{"client_id": 3 , "invoice_month" : "June 2020", "count": 1}
```

Here I'm using **aggregate** below but it count all duplicate

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "client_id": "1",
            "invoice.account_status": "Active"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$invoice"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": '$invoice.invoice_month',
            "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What makes a document duplicates?

Comment: Actually I want to get count based on month and client_id so I don't want repetation count for the month @TomSlabbaert

Comment: So we can just not count as the count will always be 1?

Comment: yes I want to set 1 for particular client_id based on month @TomSlabbaert

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand the the problem is or what you're trying to achieve. it seems like the aggregation you posted works fine?

Comment: my aggregate query produce this result   {"client_id": 1 , "invoice_month" : "July 2020", "count": 3}. It counts all duplicates of month but I want to display count:1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219488/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-tom-slabbaert).

Comment: In your  aggregate query you are matching on string `"1"` but the data is numeric `1`

Comment: sorry mentioned string in client_id but I want to match client_id and get count :1 when It match the month without duplicate count

Comment: In my question I mentioned Expected result so anyone give me a solution please

Comment: can you explain more about your expectation in you question. how and why it will be count 1 and, if you match client_id: 1 and how it will return with all client_ids,

Comment: Yes but I want to match the month eg:July 2020 client_id: 1 repeats three times for this month so I want that client client count 1 because I want if that client visit that month or not

Comment: The question is not clear, can you elaborate more. Duplicates should be removed based on `client_id`, `invoice-month` right? do you need the expected count always 1?

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned stages will help you to achieve the desired result

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HCD38ZSWpWA)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { //Considering only active accounts
      "invoice.account_status": "Active"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$invoice" // reshaping the invoices
  },
  {
    $project: { //Converting string to date
      "invoice_date": {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$invoice.invoice_date",
          "format": "%d-%m-%Y"
        }
      },
      "client_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { //getting the latest invoice
      "invoice_date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": { //reshaping again to group the result
      "_id": "$client_id",
      "data": { //Only first record
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {//Projecting what is needed
      "_id": 0,
      "client_id": "$data.client_id",
      "invoice_date": "$data.invoice_date"
    }
  }
])
```

If you want to keep dates as string in the output, you can change the last stage as below

```
{
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "client_id": "$data.client_id",
      "invoice_date": {
        "$dateToString": {
          date: "$data.invoice_date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```